# Unsetting attributes of dynamic PHP objects

Tags: php, object, overloading

I have a dynamic class referenced by `$row->attributes()`, that has some overloaded (dynamic) properties, e.g. `$row->attributes()->property1`.

I want to unset property1. I've tried `$row->attributes()->__unset("property1")` and `unset($row->attributes()->property1)`. No joy.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure how well calling an unset on an object property would go (or even if it's possible). Why not just set the value to null? What's the reason the property must be full extinguished?

Comment: Writing a function that converts the attributes of an XML tag into an associative array. Giving the user the option to set a key for that array (from an attribute value), and want to remove the attribute from that array.

Comment: Are you using (or extending?) `SimpleXMLElement`?

Comment: Hi salathe, yes I am using SimpleXMLElement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear from the question whether you have used this approach, if you have, I'll remove this answer.

Take a look at [__unset](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php), simple example is:

```
class Foo
{
    public function __unset($property)
    {
        unset($this->__my_property_holder[$property]);
    }
}
```

You simply need to do `unset($row->attributes()->property1)`, and it will actually invoke `Foo->__unset('property1')`.

Comment: While your answer is correct, in this case the class is built into the PHP source code (SimpleXMLElement) so I can't modify it. Perhaps it is an implementation error.